# Debian Wheezy VPS reboots after each login

Tags: debian, reboot, vps

I have a Debian Wheezy vps on the cloud. 
 Today I tried to login using the VNC console provided by my vps service provider but everytime I login the **server automatically reboots after 5 seconds**!
 Has anything similar happened to you?
 How can you troubleshoot a problem like this in 5 seconds?
 Is this the result of a hack or what do you think is causing this?
 Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I troubleshooted similar problems with ssh access...via VNC by the time you are able to type, you are toast. Do you have ssh access?

Comment: I get connection timed out, so I suppose sshd is down. Very interesting since other services are up and running

Comment: Without ssh(d), is pretty much a no go to debug that. open a support ticket with them.

Comment: ok, wrote you an answer to clarify it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

It can be quite a few problems, ranging from a hack, a bad update, a misbehaving watchdog, corruption or a full /var/log partition, or any combination of the above.

If it is rebooting 5s seconds after you login (or rebooting *very* regularly), I would say no interactive method will work. By the time you are able to type, you will get another reboot.

I have debugged and solved similar problems in the past sending commands via ssh (also because I authenticate via RSA)

I would place my RSA key password in cache for not losing extra time (ssh-add asks for the password, ssh-agent keeps it in cache)

```
ssh-agent /bin/bash
ssh-add
```

And then did:

```
ssh -l mylogin myserver "command"
```

And had the output back in my terminal.

Since you have no sshd working, I recommend you open a ticket support request with your VPS provider.